# bookmarklet : how to get the html of the page you want to run the bookmarklet on?

Tags: javascript, data-mining, bookmarklet

javascript bookmarklets can use document object to get selected text or links. But how do I get the whole html?

I want to get the whole html so that I could retrieve specific data between html tags.

for e.g. I want to get the following text from this page
http://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/futile.html

```
futile;
```

zwecklos;

There is no manual removal or exception for end customers at LEVEL 3 - Requests are futile;

Es gibt weder manuelle Entfernungen noch Ausnahmen für Endkunden aus LEVEL 3. Anfragen sind absolut zwecklos;

after getting the html by document.documentElement.innerHTML
how do I get the above specific text from the innerhtml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

Comment: This is not always exactly the same as the original source, because browsers will add quotes to attributes, and adds closing tags if you haven't added them, etc.. The only way to get the original is to use a xmlhttprequest for the current page.

Comment: and even an XHR request isn't trustworthy, as the page may have changed for a variety of reasons... state changes, content churn, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can check my bookmarklets as [example](http://g-calendar.appspot.com/analyze). 
There are some features:
1. It is use post request, so any size of data can be send to server
2. It is use user selection from page
3. It is extract page text content using boilerpipe library.

```
<a class="button" href="javascript:function post_to_url(path,params,method){method=method||'post';var form=document.createElement('form');form.setAttribute('method', method);form.setAttribute('action',path);form.setAttribute('accept-charset','UTF-8');for(var key in params){var hiddenField=document.createElement('input');hiddenField.setAttribute('type','hidden');hiddenField.setAttribute('name',key);hiddenField.setAttribute('value',params[key]);form.appendChild(hiddenField);}document.body.appendChild(form); form.submit();};var t=((window.getSelection&&window.getSelection())||(document.getSelection&&document.getSelection())||(document.selection&&document.selection.createRange&&document.selection.createRange().text)||location.href);if(t=='')t=location.href;post_to_url('http://g-calendar.appspot.com/analyze/analyze', {withKeywords:'true', message:t, sumSize:5, return_type:'list', title:document.title, url:location.href}, 'post')">
    Summarise
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the tagname with `element.tagName`, and any attribute of that tag with `element.getAttribute('attributename')`. Would that get you the data you are trying to get?

If not, can you give us an example of the data you are trying to get?

Comment: I would traverse the dom of the page, search for the nodes that you are trying to get the content of that way. I would get the page with an XHR, and then traverse the `.responseXML`